# Has there ever been a version where Golem could be summoned without a power cell?

Tags: terraria

I've searched the wiki and it seems like ever since it was introduced, the only way to summon Golem in Terraria PC has been to use a Lihzahrd power cell at the altar. I am wondering if there is/was an exception to this, maybe in a past version as some sort of bug or something. Alternatively, if there was some way to skip Golem entirely and still do Moon Lord then I would also take that as an answer. 
I want to clarify that this isn't a question about how to progress in Terraria. I'm just trying to theory-craft a very dumb challenge run and I'm curious about whether it's possible to get past Golem without the power cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no way around the Golem to get to the Moon Lord, not even with [Secret World Seeds](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Secret_world_seeds).

Comment: I figured that was the case. Even ML summon item can't be used until post-Golem.